# Recursion does not halt in python

Tags: python, recursion, quicksort

I'm trying to recursively implement quicksort in python, and I've run into a problem. This code should stop recursing once each iteration of quicksort has a length of 1, but it never does. Anyone have any idea why?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import fileinput
import numpy as np
import string

def Quicksort(arrayIn, start, end):
    pivot = end
    temp = 0

    if end <= start:
        return

    for e in range(1, len(arrayIn)):
        if arrayIn[e] > arrayIn[pivot]:
            temp = arrayIn[pivot]
            arrayIn[pivot] = arrayIn[e]
            arrayIn.pop(e)
            arrayIn.insert((pivot - 1), temp)

    Quicksort(arrayIn, 0, (pivot - 1))
    Quicksort(arrayIn, (pivot + 1), (len(arrayIn) - 1))

for line in fileinput.input():
    myList = line.split(",")

noSpace = [x.strip(' ') for x in myList]

myArray = []

for x in noSpace:
    myArray.append(x)

Quicksort(myArray, 0, (len(myArray) - 1))
print myArray
```

Comment: You never change the length of `arrayIn` and never use the value of `start`.

Comment: Can you post an example of file to load in `fileinput`?

Comment: @Kit 's comment and further, you are storing the input numbers as strings!!! This leads to terrible issues when you compare the contents of `arrayIn`! Try *print "22" < "3" in Python 2/3 for a surprise!  :P

Comment: The file loaded into fileinput is just a text file with a list of comma separated numbers, like 1, 5, 6, 8, 12, 3, 9, 16, 0. About half of the difficulty of this has come from trying to parse the input like that, any help on that would be appreciated.

Comment: @Runic Oh, just use int(x) or float(x) during the `myArray.append` call!

Comment: @Runic It's been some time since I implemented quick sort... but shouldn't there be a partition algorithm implementation somewhere within the quicksort? :o